# How to change eloquent query with eager loading to simple mysql query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, mysql-8.0

I have the following code and would like to know if there is a command in laravel to display the mysql query fromt this eloquent query with the eager loading also:

```
$data = Recruitment::find($id);
    $candidates = $data->candidates()
                    ->with(['media','jobTitle','previousEmployments','qualifications',
                        'status'=> function ($query) use ($id)
                        {
                            return  $query->where('recruitment_id', $id);
                        },
                        'interviews.media',
                        'recruitment_status' => function ($query) use ($id){
                            return  $query->where('recruitment_id', $id);
                        },
                        'interviews'=> function ($query) use ($id)
                        {
                            return  $query->where('recruitment_id', $id);
                        },
                        'contracts'=> function ($query) use ($id)
                        {
                            return  $query->where('recruitment_id', $id);
                        },
                        'offers'=> function ($query) use ($id, $data)
                        {
                            return  $query->where('recruitment_id', '=', $id);
                        }
                    ])
                    ->get();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: with the debugbar you can see any query that is ran by eloquent

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is in Laravel you can check the sql by following way instead of `get()` at the end of the query just use `->toSql();` then `dd($data)` then it will show you the running Query

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution using

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

before the query
and then after the query

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```